# Make new colum based on values in two different columns by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want make a 'new column' with values from 'number' only for 'sp.name' (grouping variable) where both responses 'young' and 'adult' are present; if not, enter 0 in the 'new column'.

```
df <- data.frame(sp.name= c('a','a', 'b', 'b' ,'c', 'd' ),
                 number=c(2,2,3, 3,4,4),
                 stage= c('adult', 'young', 'young','adult', 'adult', 'young'))
```

Here is what I tried.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sp.name) %>%
  mutate(new_column = ifelse('young' %in% stage & 'adult' %in% stage, 
                                             number[stage == 'adult'], 0))
```

But my code reproduces value for 'young' also to the new column, I want only values related to 'adult'.

Desired output:

| name | number | stage | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | adult | 2 |
| a | 2 | young | 0 |
| b | 3 | young | 0 |
| b | 3 | adult | 3 |
| c | 4 | adult | 0 |
| d | 4 | young | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(sp.name) %>% 
  mutate(new = (any(stage == 'adult') & any(stage == 'young') & stage == 'adult') * number)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   sp.name [4]
#>   sp.name number stage   new
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a            2 adult     2
#> 2 a            2 young     0
#> 3 b            3 young     0
#> 4 b            3 adult     3
#> 5 c            4 adult     0
#> 6 d            4 young     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ifelse condition:

```
df %>% 
mutate(new_column = ifelse( sp.name == "a" & stage %in% c("young", "adult"), number , 0))

  sp.name number stage new_column
1       a      2 adult          2
2       a      2 young          2
3       b      3 young          0
4       b      3 adult          0
5       c      4 adult          0
6       d      4 young          0
```

Comment: It only gives output for a but like @Maël suggeted I was looking for all the values that have both responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have groups with `any` of `stage == "young"` & `"adult"` (group level conditions) and `stage == "adult"` (row-level condition):

```r
df %>%
  group_by(sp.name) %>%
  mutate(new_column = ifelse(any(stage == "young") & any(stage == "adult") & stage == "adult", 
                             number[stage == 'adult'], 0))

  sp.name number stage new_column
1 a            2 adult          2
2 a            2 young          0
3 b            3 young          0
4 b            3 adult          3
5 c            4 adult          0
6 d            4 young          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new_column := number *(all(c("young", "adult") %chin% stage) & 
    stage == "adult"), sp.name]
```

-output

```
> df
   sp.name number stage new_column
1:       a      2 adult          2
2:       a      2 young          0
3:       b      3 young          0
4:       b      3 adult          3
5:       c      4 adult          0
6:       d      4 young          0
```